# Confused about java constructors

Tags: java, constructor

So I am learning `Java`. I am up to `constructors`, and dealing with `classes`. I am having some issues understanding exactly what they do/are for? I believe they are used similar to a **function call, passing parameters** to a function when called?

Am I correct in this thinking?

So for example:

```
class test{
    void durp(String input){
        System.out.print(input);
    }
}
```

If I was to make an object in my main class like this:

`test object = new test("hey");`

it would pass `hey` as a string to `durp()`

Is this correct?

Comment: I don't see any explicit constructor definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I was to make an object in my main class like this: test object = new test("hey"); it would pass "hey" as a string to durp() right?

No, because your method `durp()` is not the Constructor. It's simply a method belonging to the class and can be called from a created living object.

```
public class Test {
    /** this is a constructor */
    public Test() {
    } 

    /** this is also a constructor with a parameter */
    public Test(String arg1) { 
        System.out.println(arg1); 
    } 

    /** this is a method of Test */
    public void derp() {
    }
}
```

You can read [this tutorial from oracle about constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

Comment: Riiight, so a constructor is basicly a method with the same name as the class that gets data from the object then passes it on to a method in that class?

Comment: In a simple way, yes. A constructor is a function with the same name as the class. You can have lots of them. With parameters, without, with 2, with 3. It is called when you instantiate an object like Test test1 = new Test(); - but your constructors must be unique. The linked tutorial explains it very simple with examples.

Comment: Right, I *think* I get it. If not I will re-read it lol-thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
class Test{

     // this is a constructor (name is same as class and no return type)
    public Test(String input){
      // some code here
   }

  // this is a method 
  public void durp(String input){
   // some code
  } 

 public static void main(String[] args){
       Test test = new Test("hey"); // calls constructor
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java constructors only look like functions <sup>*</sup>, but in reality they are very different:

- You invoke a method when the object is fully initialized; you invoke a constructor when the object does not exist yet
- Methods cannot alter `final` variables of the class; for constructors, that's part of their purpose
- Methods may return different things; constructors return nothing
- Method invocations may be used in all kinds of expressions; constructors can be invoked only as part of a `new` expression.

Constructors must follow a special naming convention: their name must match the name of the class. In your case, that would be `test`. Usually, the task of a constructor is to set up member variables of the class. Given that your `test` class has no such variables, you do not need a constructor <sup>**</sup>: a simple call like this is sufficient:

```
new test().drup("hello");
```

---

<sup>*</sup> In Java, the proper term for a "function call" is "method invocation", although programmers with backgrounds in other programming languages often use these two terms interchangeably.

<sup>**</sup> When the class does not define custom constructors, a default one taking no arguments is provided for you.

Comment: You should have used the word "method" instead of "function".

Comment: @Jesper The OP used "function call", so I decided to not overload him with too many new terms at once.

Comment: Ok, but IMO it's better to learn beginners to use the correct vocabulary.

Comment: @Jesper Fair enough, thanks for the comment! I edited the answer to mention functions, and use the proper terminology throughout the rest of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, objects are constructed. Every time you make a new object, at least one
constructor is invoked. Every class has a constructor, although if you don't create
one explicitly, the compiler will build one for you. There are tons of rules concerning
constructors, let's focus on the basic declaration rules. Here's a simple example:

```
 class Tets{
   protected Test() { } // this is Test's constructor
   protected void Test() { } // this is a badly named,
   // but legal, method
 }
```

The first thing to notice is that constructors look an awful lot like methods. A
key difference is that a constructor can't ever, ever, ever, have a return type…ever!
Constructor declarations can however have all of the normal access modifiers, and
they can take arguments (including var-args), just like methods. The other BIG
RULE, to understand about constructors is that they must have the same name as
the class in which they are declared. Constructors can't be marked static (they
are after all associated with object instantiation), they can't be marked final
or abstract (because they can't be overridden). Here are some legal and illegal
constructor declarations:

```
 class Foo2 {
    // legal constructors
    Foo2() { }
    private Foo2(byte b) { }
    Foo2(int x) { }
    Foo2(int x, int... y) { }
    // illegal constructors
    void Foo2() { } // it's a method, not a constructor
    Foo() { } // not a method or a constructor
    Foo2(short s); // looks like an abstract method
    static Foo2(float f) { } // can't be static
    final Foo2(long x) { } // can't be final
    abstract Foo2(char c) { } // can't be abstract
    Foo2(int... x, int t) { } // bad var-arg syntax
}
```

visit https://java.net/downloads/jfjug/SCJP%20Sun%20Certified%20Programmer%20for%20Java%206-0071591060.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn core java basic which tells you about **constructors** with parameters.

```
class test{

public test(String s)
{
   durp(s);
}

 void durp(String input){

  System.out.print(input);

} 
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
   test obj=new test("hey");
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Constructors in java are used for constructing an object, e.g. you want to set the value of durp(not durp() because that's a method) you can use the constructor for such tasks.

I think you want someting like this:

```
class Test {
    private String durp;

    public Test(String durp) {
        //set value of durp
        this.durp = durp;
    }

    //function for getting durp string.
    //Use getDurp() rather than durp() in java.
    public String getDurp() {
        return durp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In OOP, a *constructor* is something that put life into classes. *Methods* (in OOP they are methods, not *functions*) just execute something with already existant object (previously created with a constructor). Every class has its default constructor (a parameterless constructor) unless you redefine your own constructor. In your case:

```
class Test{
   String durp;
   public Test(String anInput)
   {
      this.durp = anInput;
   }

   void durp(){
      System.out.print(input);
   }
}
```

At this point elsewhere in your code you should have a method that construct your class, for example:

```
Test test = new Test("hey");
test.durp() // prints "hey" (without quote)
```

*Note: As naming convention class name always start with an upper-case and camel notations (ie. ThisIsMyClass), in this case `Test`. The arguments is really wide and there are a lot of new things you gotta learn.*